# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.Strings.isNullOrEmpty

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to upload the users profile Image in the Google Cloud Storage when i run my application in local It does not affect the oAuth flow and the image uploading is also fine. But when I deploy the same  into Google App Engine Image uploading flow fails by throwing an Runtime exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.Strings.isNullOrEmpty

Here is my code

```
    private static GCSUpload gcs = null;
    public static synchronized GCSUpload instance() {
        if (gcs == null)
            gcs = new GCSUpload();
        return gcs;
    }
```

I included the following jars

google-api-client-1.4.1-beta
google-api-client-1.5.0-beta

I also include other jar files needed.
   Removing google-api-client-1.4.1-beta jar fails the image uploading flow in local itself  and removing google-api-client-1.5.0-beta jar fails oAuth flow in local itself adding these jar works properly in local but not in GAE 
Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: I am getting exception in this line  gcs = new GCSUpload();

Comment: please, add the stacktrace. Although it seems the jar for google-api-client is not in the classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you uploading your code? If you're using Eclipse, be wary of adding external libraries that don't "follow" your code when you deploy.  Make sure all external jars you add are in WEB-INF/lib.

This was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637594/gae-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-appengine-api-blobstore-blobsto).

Comment: I have all the jars in WEB-INF/lib as well as in build path.